# Print out Django Admin list results only

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to print out `Django Admin`'s change_list page without including the filers? For example, if the page at `0.0.0.0:8000/admin/<app>/<object>/` shows the following

[image: Complete page]

I want to create a button that, when clicked, prints only this.

[image: The only thing I need printed]

I realize that I could just remove `list_filter` but for some pages, I need them to be there

Comment: Why not just remove `list_filter` attribute?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by *print out*? What are you trying to accomplish? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @sytech Apologies, added photos for reference

Comment: @nik_m I would except I need them for some pages

Comment: You could probably make a template for this. A minimal approach can probably do this with some simple CSS. Look for information on customizing the look of the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `get_list_filter` method in your `ModelAdmin` subclass and define logic here that can disable filters just by returning empty list or tuple. For example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['class']

    def get_list_filter(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('no_filters') == '1':
            return []
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_list_filter(request)
```

Comment: Short and simple. Thanks Gwyn!